# ros servo control arduino fails

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to get the control of a servo under ROS, for that I am using arduino UNO, following this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Servo%20Controller).
When I run the rosserial_python serial_node.py at the moment when I publish the angle I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "/home/jcardenasc93/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 82, in <module>
    client.run()



File "/home/jcardenasc93/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 495, in run
    self.requestTopics()
  File "/home/jcardenasc93/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 392, in requestTopics
    self.port.flushInput()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 500, in flushInput
    termios.tcflush(self.fd, TERMIOS.TCIFLUSH)
termios.error: (5, 'Input/output error')
```

Could anyone help me please? I don't understand why this is happening

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225490/ros-servo-control-arduino-fails/) by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2016-02-01**:
does your user have permission to access the serial port?

did you try specifying the port to use?

rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/**ttyUSB0**

or

rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/**ttyACM0**

**Comment by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on 2016-02-01**:
Yes @gary-servin I changed the permission with chmod and at the moment to run the rosserial_python serial_node.py I gave the port parameter (in my case /dev/ttyACM0). At the beginning it looks like works, but when the servo begin to move the node crashes.

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2016-02-02**:
can you try disconnecting the servos and running the serial node again? If it works without the servo, then it should be a problem related with the power supply, the regulator on the arduino can't provide enough current to the servo and it resets the arduino when you try to move the motor

**Comment by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on 2016-02-10**:
Many thanks that was the problem there isn't enough current. With an external power supply it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem as @gary-servin said below it was for insufficient current. That solves with an external power supply.

---

Originally posted by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) with karma: 70 on 2016-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2016-05-26**:
external power supply for arduino or motor?

**Comment by [NeoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/38111/neom/) on 2018-10-22**:
I had the same problem and it was an excess of demanded current from the servo, thanks for the solution